# Genetic algorithms under R, adding suggestions

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm

In the genalg package, the rbga.bin command offers the possibility to add a list of suggestion, however, I can't find any example of this feature actually working, could anyone give me some help ?

```
library(genalg)


evaluation<-function(x){   
   n<- 2 
   if (sum(x)!= n){ 
      return(100)   }   
   if (sum(x)== n){
      sequen<- which(x>0)
      l=sum(sequen)
      return(-l)   } }

vect1<-rep(0,times=40) 
vect1[c(1,2)]<-c(1,1) 
sug<-list(vect1) 
for (iin 2:100){   
  vect1<-sample(vect1)   
  sug[[i]]<-vect1 
}


 GAmodel <- rbga.bin(size=40,popSize =100, iters =100, suggestions=sug,mutationChance = 0.01,elitism =T, evalFunc=evaluation,verbose=T)
```

Comment: there is a bug in rbga.bin implementation of `suggestion` argument, try N-1 suggestions, where N is population size (another parameter)

Answer (score 3):

Although documentation for `rbga.bin` function says:

> suggestions:   optional list of suggested chromosomes

`rbga.bin` apparently wants a `data.frame` or `matrix`:

```
  # taken from the rbga.bin source code
  suggestionCount = dim(suggestions)[1] 
  for (i in 1:suggestionCount) {
    population[i, ] = suggestions[i, ]
  }
```

When given a matrix, it seems to work fine:

```
sug2 <- t(replicate(sample(vect1),n = 10))  # needs to be rotated. check your solution n = 99 and it will fail
GAmodel <- rbga.bin(size=40,popSize =100, iters =100, suggestions=sug2,mutationChance = 0.01,elitism =T, evalFunc=evaluation,verbose=T)
```

Output:

```
Testing the sanity of parameters...
Not showing GA settings...
Adding suggestions to first population...
Filling others with random values in the given domains...
Starting iteration 1 
Calucating evaluation values... .................................................................................................... done.
Creating next generation...
  sorting results...
  applying elitism...
  applying crossover...
  applying mutations... 40 mutations applied
Starting iteration 2 
Calucating evaluation values... .................................................................................................. done.
Creating next generation...

<...>

Starting iteration 100 
Calucating evaluation values... .................................................................................................. done.
```

Comment: Thanks Marat, it finally worked, may I ask you the right size of the suggestion matrix ? (it doesn't work if I chose the population size).

Comment: @Blofeld, the number of rows in the suggestion matrix has to be smaller than the population size

Comment: It is actually coincidental that it works. The code is wrong in that you need to transpose the replicate results. I have added a fix.